# Git repository on GitBlit return the following error " The requested URL returned error: 403"

Tags: git, github, gitblit

I have been given an access to a private repository which is hosted at an development agency. I have been given a read access to the repo. The software they are running for the repositories is **GitBlit**. I want to clone the repo on my Mac so I fire the following command on the terminal:

**git clone https://my-username@git.agency's-
name.com/r/some_string/project_name.git**

I have **logged into their system using browser and saw my project and its commit history**. But when I clone using the above command on the terminal it asks the password but I get the following output on the screen :

**fatal: unable to access 'https://my-username@git.agency's-
name.com/r/some_string/project_name.git': The requested URL returned error: 403**

**INFO** :

I know there are many questions on SO which try to solve this problem but they all are related to GitHub and solve the problem which they have to push the source to github by changing the info in the .git/config file
. I dont have that option because I dont have the source code  in the first place (I wish to download it.)

**MORE INFO**

1. I have entered password and username correctly. I have tried this many times   :|

**Assumption :**

**I assume giving 'read access' means that I can pull the code on my side but just not push the code back to the repo on their side.**

The thing is that I am not able to find the solution to this problem because information on SO is related to GitHub and not related to some private repository that has been hosted privately on **gitBlit**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your account has been granted *VIEW* permission but not *CLONE* permission.

Comment: Ok , I will check that out with the team.

Comment: You were right. The team gave me the VIEW permission but not the clone permission. They changed the permissions and now I am able to pull the code as well. Thanks :)